# db:seed error at one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm importing some data with rake db:seed

```
Territory.delete_all
open("db/territories.txt") do |territories|
  territories.read.each_line do |territory|
    id, name, sales_rep_id, handed_out  = territory.chomp.split("\t")
    Territory.create!(:id => id, :name => name, :sales_rep_id => sales_red_id, :handed_out => handed_out)
  end
end
```

Here is my data

My data

```
9 Territory 1   2009-08-01  6   2010-07-01
10 Territory 1  2009-08-01  6   2010-07-01
11 Territory 3  2009-09-01  5
```

Everything works just fine, but the first record. After the import it has the ID = 0 instead of 9. Beginning with the secord record the IDs are correct 10, 11, 12, etc.

Why?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

What database?  You can't force the :id the way you are doing it there.  My guess is that the code tries, which advances the sequence to the that point so that you're remaining records just happen to match up.  If you change the order of your txt file, does it still work?

In any event... you can do this... replace the create! line with this:

```
territory = Territory.new do |t|
  t.id = id
  t.name = name
  t.sales_rep_id = sales_rep_id
  t.handed_out = handed_out
end
t.save!
```

Comment: I'm using SQLite3. I tried to replace my code with your code and it says: undefined local variable or method `t' for main:Object. Not sure why...